# Dictionary of One Generic Type

Tags: c#, performance, object, collections, boxing

I'm writing a program that reads some 3D virtual models and then writes some info (of different types such as int, float, datetime, etc) to an SQL db.
The db has many tables all with different structures (different number of columns of different types), so I want to write a method to insert to the db in a way that is generic enough that I don't have to write a specific method for every table.
To do so I build the SQL command with a StringBuilder using a Dictionary to give the right parameters from the method invoking the inserting method:

```
    public static object WriteDbTable(string tableName, Dictionary<string, object> valuesToWrite)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection =
                new SqlConnection(ConnectToDB().ConnectionString))
            {
                // Open connection to db
                connection.Open();

                // Create SQL command object
                SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

                // Build string with list of columns where to input values in db
                // To be plugged into command creation
                StringBuilder columnsString = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < valuesToWrite.Keys.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i < valuesToWrite.Keys.Count - 1)
                    {
                        columnsString.Append('[' + valuesToWrite.Keys.ElementAt(i) + "], ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        columnsString.Append('[' + valuesToWrite.Keys.ElementAt(i) + "]");
                    }
                }

                // Build string with list of values to input in db
                // To be plugged into command creation
                StringBuilder valuesString = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < valuesToWrite.Keys.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i < valuesToWrite.Keys.Count - 1)
                    {
                        valuesString.Append('@' + valuesToWrite.Keys.ElementAt(i) + ", ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        valuesString.Append('@' + valuesToWrite.Keys.ElementAt(i));
                    }
                }

                // Build the SQL instruction
                command.CommandText = string.Format(
                    "insert into {0} ({1}) values ({2});",
                    tableName,
                    columnsString,
                    valuesString
                    );

                // build command values
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in valuesToWrite)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@{pair.Key}", pair.Value);
                }

                // Execute command getting back the identity (/primary key) of the insertion
                return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

So in this way, in the main method I can, for example call this:

```
    private void WriteTimestamp()
    {
        // What time is the audit starting?
        DateTime timestamp = DateTime.Now;
        // Write file information to the AUDITS table
        Dictionary<string, object> stamp = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "auditDate", timestamp }
        };
    }
```

And the time after I can call this without writing a specific method for it:

```
    private void WriteGenericFileInfo(int auditId, string filePath)
    {
        // Write file information to the FILES table
        Dictionary<string, object> fileInfo = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "auditId", auditId },
            { "projectId", 2 },
            { "disciplineId", 1 },
            { "filePath", filePath },
            { "fileSize", Utilities.BytesToMB(new FileInfo(filePath).Length) }
        };
    }
```

Now, this works great as I just have to manage one method to write whatever type of data in the database in tables that all have different numbers of columns of different types.
The **problem** though is that I have to implicitly **box** the Value of of dictionary every time and at some point I will have to write a few thousand entries in a single run of the program, so I'm afraid that this will **impact the performance** terribly (of the program not of the db).

Using the *dynamic* type of course is not a solution either as it would still box the value to an object.

What could I do to avoid boxing in this situation, and hence achieve better performance?

Thanks for any tip!

Comment: First problem is being afraid of the impact of something that you *haven't measured* and have no proof that there will even be an impact. The second problem is that you haven't explained what target performance are you after, so we have no clue whether this is fast enough, too slow, consumes too much RAM or whatever.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I understand it's a generic question but considering that **boxing could take up to 20 times longer than a simple reference assignment** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/performance-tips#boxing-and-unboxing) I thought it would be better to think of it from the beginning. I was just wondering if the community could think of a better solution than mine.

Comment: Costing 20 times more than a couple of microseconds doesn't worry me. You can use generics if you use Dapper/EF/NHibernate, but then the actual queries will take longer probably

Comment: Yes true, the issue is that at some point I will be writing a few thousand lines in a single run and then the cost will become exponential no?   
I was checking Dapper's examples and see you can use _object_ types / generics, but wouldn't that be the same issue as I would be boxing anyway? Maybe I'm looking at the wrong examples?

Comment: `SqlParameter`'s `Value` property is of type `System.Object` so *any* value-type value you add as a parameter is going to get boxed anyway. I'm not even going to suggest a way around it because it's vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Using ORM is better option than maitaining dictionary for the columns and values. It can break easily when database table schema changes. Also the way you are generating sql queries, it is open to sql injection.

Comment: Good point actually! I don't know how I haven't noticed it in the first place!!
ORM it is then
@madreflection very interesting! I didn't know that

Comment: @madreflection sorry I don't understand what's your alternative idea.
Also, so there's no sql injection? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @AndreaTassera - I never said what the idea was because it's a Bad Idea™.

Comment: @madreflection ok I think I'm getting lost and comments are getting deleted. Anyway, is my code open to sql injection? Shall I use an ORM?

Comment: Yeah, at least one of my comments got deleted, so I understand. Anyway, how protected this code is from SQL injection depends on how strictly you enforce limitations on your dictionary keys, and I don't see that here at all. Long story short, **yes, you should use an ORM.**

Comment: @madreflection yes there's no checking of the input because there's no input from user. What my program (which is going to be only for internal use) does is to go through a file containing a virtual 3D model of a building (architecture and engineering), extract some information and write that to a db. What could potentially happen is that someone will name an element maliciously and break the db.
Ok I'll definitely use an ORM! Thanks for the suggestion!!